# same get_posts function works diffrently in tag.php and functions.php

Tags: functions, ajax, get-posts

I have a strange issue that i don't really understand, I explain :
In my `tag.php`, i have an infinite scroll with custom post types thanks to the active tag and ajax.

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'video',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__not_in' => $posts_not_in,
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field'    => 'id',
                'terms'    => $theme->term_id,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
     )
)) ;
```

I do the same get_posts in `functions.php` in my ajax function

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_posts_theme', 'get_posts_theme' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_posts_theme', 'get_posts_theme' );

function get_posts_theme() { ... }
```

and it displays differents posts results. Why ? Any ideas ? Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0):

Some arguments for your query are with variables, we don't know how you define them in the function. i.e : $posts_not_in can be the same or not. And will change your results. Same for $terms.

You maybe need to introduce an offset var and add it to each query.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i restart, even this simple get_posts not returning same values !

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'video',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
)) ;
```

I replaced 'paged' with 'offset' and nothing changed !

How it's possible ? What i forgot ?

If i add 'order' => 'ASC' and 'orderby' => 'ID' for example, it's the worst !

I have a problem with my custom post type video because if i replace by 'posts' it works well !